# Exposing AKS cluster application using ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am trying to expose my application inside the AKS cluster using ingress:
It creates a service and an ingress but somehow does not assign an address to the ingress. What could be a possible reason for this?

### apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: dockerdemo
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: dockerdemo
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: dockerdemo
spec:
nodeSelector:
"kubernetes.io/os": linux
containers:
- name: dockerdemo
image: devsecopsacademy/dockerapp:v3
env:
- name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
value: "yes"
resources:
requests:
cpu: 100m
memory: 128Mi
limits:
cpu: 250m
memory: 256Mi
ports:
- containerPort: 80
name: redis

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: dockerdemo-service
spec:
type: ClusterIP
ports:

- port: 80
  selector:
  app: dockerdemo

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: my-ingress15
annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-rounting
spec:
rules:

- host: curefirsttestapp.cluster15-dns-c42b65ee.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io
  http:
  paths:

  - path: /
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
    service:
    name: dockerdemo-service
    port:
    number: 80

Answer (score 2):

Well, first make sure your application is up and functionning inside your K8s Cluster using a port-forword to your localhost

```bash
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE port-forward svc/$SERVICE :$PORT
```

if app is reachable and your call are getting back 200 Status, you can now move to the ingress part:

1. Make sure ingress controller is well installed under your services

```bash
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get svc
```

2. Add a DNS record in your DNS zone which maps your `domain.com` to ingress controller `$EXTERNAL_IP`
3. Take a look at the ingress you created for your `$SERVICE`

```bash
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get ingress
```

4. At this stage, if you application is well running and also the the ingress is well set, the app should be reachable trough `domain.com`, otherwise we'll need further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) deployed. This is a load balancer service which can have either a public or private ip depending on your situation.
2. Make sure you have an ingress definition which has a rule to point to your service. This is the metadata which will tell your ingress controller how to route requests to its ip address. These routing rules can contain how to handle paths like `strip`, `exact`, etc....